# Spark is very slow when joining multiple dataframes

Tags: performance, scala, apache-spark, join

I am trying to join multiple dataframes:

```
DF1: count =2296872, No of partitions= 8                                                 
DF2: count = 113274, No of partitions = 4
DF3: count = 1351189, No of partitions = 8
DF4: count = 152291, No of partitions = 2
DF5: count = 481527, No of partitions = 8
DF6: count = 481518, No of partitions = 8
DF7: count = 7714, No of partitions = 1
DF8: count = 39521, No of partitions = 1
DF9: count = 4086, No of partitions = 1
DF10: count == 481527, No of partitions = 8
```

Additionally, I use SPARK_SQL_SHUFFLE_PARTITIONS=2000

Code:

```
val joinedDfs =listContainingMultipleDfs.foldLeft(broadcast(smallerDf))((a, b) => a.join(b, Seq("key"), "left"))

    joinedDfs.write.
              option("header", "false").
              option("quote", null).
              option("delimiter", Delimiter).
              csv(tempPath) // AWS path
```

How do I increase my performance in Spark?

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:326)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1134)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
```

It took 4 hours to do the joins and then while trying to save to S3, it died of the above error.

Specs: 
TOTAL_EXECUTOR_CORES:-8

EXECUTOR_MEMORY:-'4g'

DRIVER_MEMORY:-'4g'

Comment: Based on the row count and the number of incoming partitions you listed, you should probably not increase shuffle partitions to 2000. How many cores do you have across your cluster?

Comment: How slow is your "very slow"? What is the average size of your entries in these DF's? What type of network do you have in your spark cluster? What is the executor configuration? May be more in depth understanding of Spark will help - https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/

Comment: @Silvio I'm running this on my local machine with 
TOTAL_EXECUTOR_CORES:-8
EXECUTOR_MEMORY:-'4g'
DRIVER_MEMORY:-'4g'

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh It took 4 hours for the join on TOTAL_EXECUTOR_CORES:-8 EXECUTOR_MEMORY:-'4g' DRIVER_MEMORY:-'4g' configuration. And then while I was trying to write it to S3, the job died with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: So given that you're joining all these DFs one by one you can't parallelize this beyond 1 join at a time. So first, I would simply reduce the shuffle partitions to 8 since you're only running 8 cores in local mode. Also, if you're just running in local mode I don't think `TOTAL_EXECUTOR_CORES` will take affect, so just run it with spark master set to `local[*]`.